# Size of array in codeigniter, native PHP function support

Tags: php, codeigniter

As per documentation, I've tried below code to find size of array in codeigniter

```
 echo element('size', $get, NULL);
```

but it ended up showing following error

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\wamp\www\cinifb_ci\system\helpers\array_helper.php on line 46
```

I've tried to load content of `$get` into another array variable, but it continued showing the above error.

Please suggest me the alternative ways along with solving this.

I've tried to using native PHP solutions like

```
echo size_array($get);
```

but It ended up in

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function size_array()
```

**Does this mean I'm not supposed to use native PHP functions in CodeIgniter**

Comment: `size_array()` is not a native PHP function...

Comment: i dont know codeigniter, but in native PHP size of array can we fetched with count($array_name).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within CodeIgniter, this expression:

```
element('size', $get, null)
```

Only works if `$get` is an array **and** it has an index `'size'`; if it is an array, it would be more likely that you meant this:

```
count($get);
```

However, in your case, `$get` is actually an object, `stdClass` to be exact; determining the size of that object requires another step:

```
count(get_object_vars($get));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
count($array);
```

That's the native function to get the size of an array ;)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
$completed_requests = $this->db->where('status' => SOLICITACAO_FINALIZADA)
                                       ->where('trip_occurred' => OCORREU)
                                       ->count_all_results('transport_requests');
```

> **->count_all_results('TABLE_NAME');**